Dynamically load image by name
I am learning. I'm doing a delivery layout.
I reached a part where I need to load Cards with the restaurants, the names are going correctly, but I can't place the images.
I'm using a JSON file, with a 'restaurants' type, containing id, name, image.
File structure:
/
|--/src
     |--/App
     |    |--index.tsx
     |--/components
     |    |--/restaurants
     |         |--index.tsx
     |         |--/restaurantCard
     |              |--index.tsx
     |--/assets
          |--/restaurants
               |--all images png

RestaurantCard Component:
import { View, Text, Pressable, Image } from 'react-native'

import { RestaurantsProps } from '..'
import { FontAwesome, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'



export default function RestaurantCard({ item }: { item: RestaurantsProps }) {

    const width = 140; 
    const height = 100;

    // This line works
    const Logo = Image.resolveAssetSource(require(`@/src/assets/restaurants/kfc.png`)).uri

    // This dont works
    // const Logo = Image.resolveAssetSource(require(`@/src/assets/restaurants/${item.image}`)).uri

    return (
        <Pressable style={{
            marginVertical: 4,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#c8c8c8',
            borderRadius: 16,
        }}
            onPress={() => { console.log(`CLICOU EM ${item.name}`) }}
        >
            <View style={{
                width: width,
                height: height,
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                borderRadius: 16,
            }}>
                <Image source={{uri: Logo}} style={{
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    resizeMode: 'stretch',
                    borderRadius: 16,
                }} />
            </View>
            <FontAwesome name='circle' size={38} color={'#aaa'} style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 26,
            }} />
            <Ionicons name='fast-food-outline' size={24} style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 32,
                color: '#ddd'
            }} />
            <Text className='font-semibold text-gray-600 text-lg mt-5'>{item.name}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    )
}

Restaurant list component:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import RestaurantCard from './restaurantCard';

import * as restaurantesJson from '@/db.json'

export interface RestaurantsProps {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string
}

export function Restaurants({ urlFetch }: { urlFetch: string }) {

    const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState<RestaurantsProps[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        //This async function was an attempt, but nothing changed
        async function getRestaurantsJson() {
            // console.log(data);
            setRestaurants(restaurantesJson.restaurants); 

            console.log(restaurants);
        }

        getRestaurantsJson()
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                data={restaurants}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <RestaurantCard item={item} />}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    gap: 12,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

I don't know what I have to do
I need an solution that loads the images automatically, without needing me to create a file exporting them all.

we can solve these is different approach
Note: your RestaurantsProps image name and local assets image name should be same
Like:
load all images in to a local array like


const img = {
"kfc.png": require('@/src/assets/restaurants/kfc.png'),
  "mcdonalds.png": require('@/src/assets/restaurants/mcdonalds.png'),
.....,
}
 ..

const logo = img[item.image]

<Image source={Logo}>




The issue you're encountering arises from the fact that dynamic imports using require() in React Native do not work directly with variables.
To solve this, you can use a workaround by preloading the images into an object that maps image filenames to require statements. Here's how you can do it:
const images: { [key: string]: any } = {
"kfc": require('@/src/assets/restaurants/kfc.png'),
"burgerking": require('@/src/assets/restaurants/burgerking.png'),
"mcdonalds": require('@/src/assets/restaurants/mcdonalds.png'),
//Add other images here
}

and here's the RestaurantCard component :
export default function RestaurantCard({ item }) {
const width = 140; 
const height = 100;

// Get the image dynamically from the images object
const Logo = Image.resolveAssetSource(images[item.image]).uri;

return (
    <Pressable style={{ marginVertical: 4, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#c8c8c8', borderRadius: 16 }}
        onPress={() => console.log(`Clicked on ${item.name}`)}>
        <View style={{ width: width, height: height, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 16 }}>
            <Image source={{uri: Logo}} style={{ width: width, height: height, resizeMode: 'stretch', borderRadius: 16 }} />
        </View>
        <FontAwesome name='circle' size={38} color={'#aaa'} style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 26 }} />
        <Ionicons name='fast-food-outline' size={24} style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 32, color: '#ddd' }} />
        <Text className='font-semibold text-gray-600 text-lg mt-5'>{item.name}</Text>
    </Pressable>
);
}

!! Ensure that the image field in your JSON data matches the filenames exactly, for example: "kfc"

I already knew about this solution, that's probably what I'm going to do. But I thought in case I have several images. I thought about how I could do this automatically, without having to write code importing all the images manually.
But thank you very much for your help!
